# Build custom FILTER_VALIDATE_XY for filter_input_array

Tags: php, validation, passwords

I cant find anything about building a custom validation function to use within filter_input_array.

Is there a possibility to validate against one of my own functions?

something like

```
function FILTER_CUSTOM_FUNCTION($input) { // do something }    

$filter = array(

       'id' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
       'action' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
       'custom_var' => FILTER_CUSTOM_FUNCTION

);

$myArray = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET, $filter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is the keyword "FILTER_CALLBACK":

```
function check_languages($var) {
    static $called = 0;
    $called++;
    echo "called: $called: $var<br />";
    $var = filter_var($var, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRIPPED);
    $l = new language($var);
    return $l;
}
$filter = array(
   'favourites' => array(
                            'filter' => FILTER_CALLBACK,
                            'options'  => 'check_languages'
                        )
);
```

via http://devzone.zend.com/703/php-built-in-input-filtering/